# displaying the product price different in the different browsers in the wordpress site normally am using chrome when i see in the mozilla

Tags: wordpress

I am working with the wordpress website and I am facing some issues regarding the browsers.

When I open my website link in the google chrome then the product price coming including tax in the index page and when I open the website with mozilla firefox then it is showing product price without tax.

I want to show the same price in the all the browsers in the same way but it is showing in fractional values.

why its happening and how to fix this?

Comment: share your code or url of site.

Comment: i cant share the code because its wordpress site

Comment: if i log in from the admin panel and see the website its showing including tax, if i see the website normally means like user its showing the product price excluding tax